# PostgreSQL: UPDATE trigger on table with OID columns doesn't fire for lo_put-based UPDATEs

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I've created an UPDATE trigger on a table containing an OID column. The intent here is to copy any changes from the OID column to a related BYTEA column.

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE blah01 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    oid_a oid NOT NULL,
    bytea_a bytea
);


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX blah01_pkey ON blah01(id int4_ops);
```

and trigger:

```
create or replace function blah01_insert_trigger_fnc ()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    new.bytea_a:= lo_get(new.oid_a);
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger blah01_insert_trigger
before update on blah01
for each row execute procedure blah01_insert_trigger_fnc();
```

The trigger gets called with `UPDATE blah01 ...;` statements, and the BYTEA column gets a copy of the large object as expected.

**Problem is it never fires when someone invokes `lo_put(<some LOID from pg_largeobject also in blah01.oid_a>, ...);`.**

I fully understand this happens because `lo_put` is directly modifying `pg_largeobject`, and there's no real change to `blah01`.  **What I'm after is some reasonable way to have the update to `pg_largeobject` trigger the update to the `blah01` table (and a couple dozen others with similar setups).**

Comment: There is no way to do that. One of the reasons to avoid large objects.